# .NET XmlSerializer and decimals

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I used xsd.exe on a remote xsd file to generate some C# class definitions. One type is defined as

```
<xs:element name="amount">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
            <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

When I try to deserialize an xml file I get the error:

```
There is an error in XML document (30, 12). ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

This only seems to happen when there's a comma used as a grouping separator (i.e 87,000). If I go through and delete the commas wherever there's an error deserialization works fine.

Is there some modification I can make o the xsd to allow for comma grouping? Or better yet a way to allow for it in my code? Trying to parse a decimal in my code with commas works fine, it's just not liking it in the xml file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"87,000" does not match the `xs:decimal` type.

There is no XSD type that permits commas.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of this datatype defines no restrictions whatsoever on the size of numbers permissible under this datatype. Unless your form processing is prepared to deal with a number thousands of digits long (or even longer), you should use a restriction on the allowed upper and lower limits, and **number of digits past the decimal point**.